# In the implement of SGI STL, what's the function of template argument "int inst" in file stl_alloc.h?

Tags: c++, stl

In the file "stl_alloc.h"

class __malloc_alloc_template is defined as

```
template <int inst>
class __malloc_alloc_template {
...
};
```

However, in the class, "inst" has never been used. So what's the function of it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class contains some static members. By using different `inst` values you get a different set of static members.